# UPDATE WHERE AND ORDER BY LIMIT

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb.net-2010

Syntax Error on UPDATE statement

```
Access.ExecQuery("UPDATE record " & _
           "SET (Time_Out=@timeout) " & _
           "WHERE Employee=@emp AND Punch_Date=@date " & _
           "ORDER BY Time_In ASC LIMIT 1;")
```

whats wrong with my syntax?

Comment: is `record ` table name ?

Comment: yes record is a table name

Comment: can you remove **ORDER BY** clause

Comment: @JohnMark - Did you check my answer, is your problem solved?

Comment: @MaheshKaria i just want to update a row where the WHERE clause has two conditions. `"WHERE Employee=@emp AND Punch_Date=@date "`

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like this :

```
Access.ExecQuery("UPDATE record " & _
           "SET (Time_Out=@timeout) " & _
           "WHERE Employee=@emp AND Punch_Date=@date;")
```

You can not use `ORDER BY` clause in `UPDATE` query.